# How to use Multiple Reducers in react native

Tags: redux, react-redux, react-native

I have two Reducers
Student Reducer and Employee Reducer, I want to use both reducer in my code but i don't know how to do that
Please help me..

```
import React from 'react'
import { Provider as PaperProvider } from 'react-native-paper'
import AppNavigator from './src/navigation'
import { Provider as StoreProvider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import studentReducer from './src/store/reducers/studentStore'
import employeeReducer from './src/store/reducers/employeeStore'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
stuedntReducer,
employeeReducer,
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

export default function App() {
return (
   <StoreProvider store={store}>
     <PaperProvider>
       <AppNavigator />
     </PaperProvider>
   </StoreProvider>
  )
}
```

Comment: Whats the error ?, combinereducer will do what you ask

Comment: This code block looks fine.
The errors probably originate from studentReducer and employeeReducer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you got an `Reference Error`, but check this.

You have imported

```
import studentReducer from './src/store/reducers/studentStore'
```

and have used in `combineReducer()`

```js
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
stuedntReducer,
employeeReducer,
});
```

So `stuedntReducer` !== `studentReducer`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { Reducers } from "../reducer/Reducers";
import { Reducers1 } from "../reducer/Reducers";
import { Reducers2 } from "../reducer/Reducers";
import { Reducers3 } from "../reducer/Reducers";
import { Reducers4 } from "../reducer/Reducers";

export const Mystore = createStore(
Reducers1
Examplereducer   // use multipal reducers
Examplereducer1
Examplereducer2
Examplereducer3
)
```